# Making operations with Multindex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, data-science

I have a GroupBy Data Frame that is similar to this one:

[image]

I want to create a column named PL as the difference between the Position of the same Product of the same Client buyed on the same day with the previous day's position. Also the first dates should have PL = 0.

The dataframe should look like this

[image]

Edit:
the unstacked dataframe looks like this:

[Link to original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doP8v.png)

Dataframe constructor:

```
data = {'Client': ['Client 1', 'Client 1', 'Client 2', 'Client 2', 'Client 1', 'Client 1', 'Client 2', 'Client 2'],
        'Position Date': ['2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03'],
        'Product': ['Product 1', 'Product 4', 'Product 2', 'Product 3', 'Product 1', 'Product 4', 'Product 2', 'Product 3'],
        'Buy Date': ['2022-05-02', '2022-06-02', '2022-03-12', '2022-01-25', '2022-05-02', '2022-06-02', '2022-03-12', '2022-01-25'],
        'Position': [100, 5000, 120, 50, 150, 7000, 200, 100]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(['Position Date', 'Client', 'Product', 'Buy Date'])
```

Comment: Please reformat your dataframe especially with MultiIindex.

Comment: Done it. Used images this time @Corralien

Comment: It's even worse with images, please read [how to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: linked the original dataframe on the link edited @mozway

Comment: It is important to post the dataframe constructor to be able to reproduce the example. It was a pain for me to create the dataframe from the images :-( You can use `df.reset_index().to_dict('list')` for example

Comment: And you last row, PL should be 50 not 100?

Comment: @Corralien yes, you're right, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with `level` as parameter of your index levels:

```
df['PL'] = df.groupby(level=['Client', 'Product', 'Buy Date']).diff().fillna(0)
print(df)

# Output
                                             Position      PL
Position Date Client   Product   Buy Date                    
2022-01-02    Client 1 Product 1 2022-05-02       100     0.0
                       Product 4 2022-06-02      5000     0.0
              Client 2 Product 2 2022-03-12       120     0.0
                       Product 3 2022-01-25        50     0.0
2022-01-03    Client 1 Product 1 2022-05-02       150    50.0
                       Product 4 2022-06-02      7000  2000.0
              Client 2 Product 2 2022-03-12       200    80.0
                       Product 3 2022-01-25       100    50.0
```

Comment: yes it does! Thank you so much. One more thing, if now my function isn't necessarily the diff, but a function like: x = PL / last day position?

Comment: Something like = `df.groupby(level=['Client', 'Product', 'Buy Date'])['PL'].apply(lambda x: print(x))`?

Comment: No, I mean using a function that divides the PL of a current day over the position of the previous day.

Comment: Can you give an example of a computed value, please?

Comment: On the 2022-01-03 Client 1 Product 1 2022-05-02, the x column would be x = PL / yesterday position = 50 / 100 = 0.5

Comment: `df.groupby(level=['Client', 'Product', 'Buy Date']).apply(lambda x: x['Position'] / x['PL'].iloc[-1])`?